# use sed to get a list of different paths up to a point

Tags: sed

I have a list of filepaths that look like this

```
abc/def/ghi/jl/r1/r2
abc/def/ghi/jl/r9/r11
abc/nyc/ghi/jl/r3/r4/r5
abc/nyc/ghi/jl/pan21/nab11
def/kyn/ghi/jl/r6
...
```

all paths have the sub-paths `/ghi/jl/`

I would like to get a list of different paths ending at `/ghi/jl/` so for the example above I would get

```
abc/def/ghi/jl/
abc/nyc/ghi/jl/
def/kyn/ghi/jl/
```

Can this achieved with sed (or something similar)? I tried

```
sed 's/\/ghi\/jl\/.*/\/ghi\/jl\//' listfile
```

but didnt quite get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`perl -ne '/(^.*?\/ghi\/jl)/; print "$1\n";' listfile | sort -u`

should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using awk

```sh
awk -F/ '{print $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 "/" $4 "/"}' /path/to/your/file
```

`-F/` tells awk to use `/` as a delimiter for splitting input.

#### Using `cut` and `sed`

```sh
{ cut -d '/' -f -4 | sed 's/$/\//'; } < /path/to/your/file
```

Here, the `cut` command splits each line in the input file, and then outputs the first 4 fields (`-f -4` tells `cut` to output the first 4 fields). Then the `sed` command appends `/` onto the end of each line output by `cut`.

If the trailing `/` on each output line is not required, this simplifies to

```sh
cut -d '/' -f -4 /path/to/your/file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` and `sort`:

```
sed -ne 's|^\(.*/ghi/jl/\).*|\1|p' -- data | sort -u
```

or,

```
somedir='/ghi/jl/'
sed -ne 's|^\(.*'"${somedir}"'\).*|\1|p' -- data | sort -u
```

where the substitution captures from start of line up to and including dirname.

Or perhaps, selecting dirnames with at least 4 slashes,

```
sed -n -e 's|/|\t|4' -e 's|\t.*|/|p' -- data | sort -u
```

where the first substitution replaces the fourth slash with a tab, the second replaces tab and following characters with the stripped slash.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` like so:

```
grep -o '.*ghi/jl/' in_file
```

Here, [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses option `-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '\#(.*/ghi/jl/).*#{s//\1/;H;g;s/((\n.*).*)\2$/\1/;h};$!d;x;s/.//' file
```

Store matches in the hold space making sure to remove any duplicates. At end of the file, switch to the hold space and print the results (less the introduced newline at the start of buffer).